# .htaccess rewrite space to dash(-)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I got a dynamic URL I want to rewrite. I want to rewrite the space into a dash to not get %20 in the URL. My attempt was to create two parts in the .htaccess and put a @ sign in the middle of it when its sending the paranmeters to my PHP file. then in the query I used:

```
str_replace('@', ' ', $_GET['location_name'])
```

I did test this by printing it to my screen and it was showing the expected result.

A working not rewrited example:

```
/shop/article-filter.php?location_name=Data Tilburg&products_choise=0
```

Needs to be:
   /shop/articles-Data-Tilburg.html

I tryed the following rewrite rule which is redirecting me to the right page but its not showing any result.  What is wrong, in the rewriterule?

```
RewriteRule ^articles-([^/]*)-([^/]*)\.html$ /shop/article-filter.php?location_name=$1@$2&products_choice=0 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try sending the whole 'Data-Tilburg' string to php, and then just replace dashes with spaces?

```
RewriteRule ^shop/articles-(.+)\.html$ /shop/article-filter.php?location_name=$1&products_choice=0 [L]
```

and then in php:

```
str_replace('-', ' ', $_GET['location_name']);
```

Presuming of course that original names don't contain dashes (your solution wouldn't work with that either).

Also be careful with that location_name string as if it contains multibyte chars str_replace() can screw them completely.